# Custom SharePoint Ribbon with SPGridView control

Tags: sharepoint

I have a custom application page in SharePoint 2010 created in VS 2010.
There are a few custom button controls in the Ribbon on this page.
This Ribbon control is implemented using SPRibbon api's.
There is a SPGridView on the page that is bound to a datasource.
What i want to achieve is enable/disable and show dialog window that is context sensitive that is when an item is selected on the SPGrid, the buton should be enabled/disabled. Also, after selection, and clicking on one button, a dialog window should open up with item id passed to this page.

Thanks...
Vinit

Comment: So... what's the question? Sounds like you have some coding to do! ;D

Comment: Yes i do have to code for this. Could it be that i get a direction as to how to go about this as i am new to SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Vinit, you can have a look at the series for Ribbon [customizations](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html)